# App Inspection says "No debuggable processes available"

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

I am trying to use the 'Database Inspector' in Android Studio. So I go to the App Inspection Tab because it was said that that was where I could find it, but under it I don't find anything, and when I select my Device, it says "No debuggable processes available". Please how do I resolve this? I am trying to open the Room Database file that I am using in my Project.

My Android Studio version is Canary 9 2021.3.1 Dolphin.

My Device is Redmi 8a Android version 9.

The screenshot below shows what I am going through...

[image]

Comment: App inspection only works for apps that are marked as debuggable. Usually only apps you compile yourself have this flag set. Apps from Play Store never have this flag set.

Comment: @Robert so how can I mark the App as debuggable?? This is a project I've been building myself but the App Inspection doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to open the Room Database file that I am using in my Project.

You can always use device explorer to copy the database file(s) *(see notes below)* and then open the database in an SQLite tool *(Navicat for SQLite, DBeaver, DB Browser for SQLite and SQLite Studio being some examples of such tools)*.

- this is the technique that could be/was utilised prior to App Inspection.
- Note that if there are files with the same names as the database but suffixed with **-wal** and **-shm** that if these files are not empty (0 bytes), then these files should also be copied as they are considered part of the database. If there is a file suffixed with **-journal** then this need not be copied.

  - -wal and -shm indicate that WAL (**W**rite-**A**head **L**oging) is being used. -jorunal indicate that Journal mode is being used. In short journal mode applies changes to the actual database file and keeps a record (log) thus allowing changes to be rolled back. Whilst WAL mode applies changes to the -wal file to later be committed to the actual database file, rollback is accomplished by removing the data from the -wal file.

As an example on an API 22 device.

Here's where **App Inspection** rejects opening the database and Device Explorer has been used to look at data/data/:-

[image]

The App/package is someway down the list if files:-

[image]

- as can be seen journal mode is used, so no -wal and -shm files needs to be copied.

Right clicking the files allows them to be **saved as** (saved as E:\saved_database_file):-

[image]

Here's an example of opening the copied database using DB Browser for SQLite (right clicking the saved file from Windows Explorer and selecting DB Browser for SQLite):-

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is the method I use already. I was just directed to the Database Inspection by someone as a way of making things easier, but the Database Inspector doesn't seem to work for no reason. Its not even there.